# Digital certificate and SAML Serialization

Tags: saml, digital-certificate

I am trying to create SAML Assertion in c#, but when I try to serialized it using WriteToken method of WSSecurityTokenSerializer class, it gives me the following exception

"The private key is not present in the X.509 certificate"

I have created the certificate using the following command,

makecert -r -pe -n "CN=CompanyXYZ Server" -b 01/01/2007 -e 01/01/2012 -sky exchange Server.cer

And for SAML assertion creation I am following the tutorial from [link text](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2007/02/22/Creating-of-SAML-token.aspx)

I am wondering how I am generate certificate which contains private key.
Or this is any way around to (create / read) un-signed SAML Assertions.

Comment: Since you're using it for signing, shouldn't it be "-sky signature"?  Can you include your version of the code that retrieves and attempts to use the certificate?  I have some sample code I could share, but it does the signing "manually" (not using WCF).

Answer (score 3):

guess what ... I figured it out. Instead of using the .cer certificate file I used .pfx file and specify the private key password during the initialization of X509Certificate2.

i.e.

```
string path = @"D:\projects\SAMLDemo\Server.pfx";

X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(path,"password");
```

Comment: Excellent!  The sample code I mentioned included how to specify password if it was needed.

Comment: Thanks Shanni ! I banged my head against the wall a few times before I ended up here.